# UIStackView setCustomSpacing at runtime

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have a horizontal `UIStackView` that, by default, looks as follows:

[image: default stack view]

The view with the heart is initially hidden and then shown at runtime. I would like to reduce the spacing between the heart view and the account name view.
The following code does the job, but *only*, when executed in `viewDidLoad`:

```
stackView.setCustomSpacing(8, after: heartView)
```

When changing the custom spacing later on, say on a button press, it doesn't have any effect. Now, the issue here is, that the custom spacing is lost, once the subviews inside the stack view change: when un-/hiding views from the stack view, the custom spacing is reset and cannot be modified.

#### Things, I've tried:

- verified the spacing is set by printing `stackView.customSpacing(after: heartView)` (which properly returns `8`)
- unsuccessfully ran several reload functions:

  - `stackView.layoutIfNeeded()`
  - `stackView.layoutSubviews()`
  - `view.layoutIfNeeded()`
  - `view.layoutSubviews()`
  - `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

How can I update the custom spacing of my stack view at runtime?

Comment: Are you calling on the main thread?

Comment: @andym, yes, I am.

Comment: Just my initial thought, but I'm afraid I have no further suggestions, sorry :-(

Comment: When/where are you setting the heart view to not be hidden?

Comment: If the user activates a certain app-mode, different controls all across the app are being displayed. One of which is the heart view. Since the user can change the app-mode at any time, I need to add the heart view at that point and then set the custom spacing. After switching the `UISwitch`, the app-mode changes and the controls are being updated.

Comment: Okay, so the screenshot you've added is showing the stack view with common spacing? And I'm guessing the custom spacing is to group the heart and account name closer together, is that right?

Comment: Exactly. However, I'd rather not use workarounds such as creating another stack view, if that's on your mind.

Comment: Ah, that is exactly what I was going to suggest haha – my next thought which is also a bit of a workaround, but could actually introduce the desired effect, is to put the change of `isHidden` and call of `setCustomSpacing` inside a `UIView.animate(withDuration: _, ...)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to make sure the `UIStackView`'s `distribution` property is set to `.fill` or `.fillProportionally`.

---

I created the following swift playground and it looks like I am able to use `setCustomSpacing` at runtime with random values and see the effect of that.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class VC: UIViewController {

    let view1 = UIView()
    let view2 = UIView()
    let view3 = UIView()
    var stackView: UIStackView!

    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view1.backgroundColor = .red
        view2.backgroundColor = .green
        view3.backgroundColor = .blue

        view2.isHidden = true

        stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3])
        stackView.spacing = 10
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally

        let uiSwitch = UISwitch()
        uiSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSwitch), for: .valueChanged)

        view1.addSubview(uiSwitch)
        uiSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            uiSwitch.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.centerXAnchor),
            uiSwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -50)
        ])
    }

    @objc public func onSwitch(sender: Any) {
        view2.isHidden = !view2.isHidden
        if !view2.isHidden {
            stackView.setCustomSpacing(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(40)), after: view2)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = VC()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: So, you gave me the hint I needed: `stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally`. My stack view's distribution was set to `equalSpacing`, which already sounds wrong in this context, ha! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Another reason `setCustomSpacing` can fail is if you call it *before* adding the arranged subview after which you want to apply the spacing.

**Won't work:**

```swift
headerStackView.setCustomSpacing(50, after: myLabel)
headerStackView.addArrangedSubview(myLabel)
```

**Will work:**

```swift
headerStackView.addArrangedSubview(myLabel)
headerStackView.setCustomSpacing(50, after: myLabel)
```

Comment: This is the answer I come back to EVERY TIME I'm using setCustomSpacing.......

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that custom spacing values get reset after hiding/unhiding children. I was able to override `updateConstraints()` for my parent view and set the custom spacing as needed. The views then kept their intended spacing.

```swift
override func updateConstraints() {
  super.updateConstraints()
  stackView.setCustomSpacing(10, after: childView)
}
```